# Create a function which returns words in the string(REMOVE CHARACTER IN STRING)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

- example 1: `"fogfogfffoooofftreesggfoogfog"` -- In this example, I need to remove `'fogFOG'` and I should get output as `'trees'`.
- example 2: `"fogFogFogffffooobirdsandthebeesGGGfogFog"` -- Output should be like `'birdsandthebees'`

```
str="fogFogFogffffooobirdsandthebeesGGGfogFog"

str1="fogFOG"

for i in str1:

    Str=str.replace(i,'')
print(Str)
```

I'm getting error at `Str=str.replace(i)`

```
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm getting output If I use all the letters separately in a list. But I would like to know how can we do it with a single string.

Comment: Indeed, [`replace` takes at least 2 arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), and it should be called on an _instance of `str`_, not the `str` class itself.

Comment: You should start by naming your variable otherwise than using reserved word like str

Comment: There is no line `Str=str.replace(i)` in the code in your question, so where does the error come from?

Comment: Please check if your code is the same as what you posted, the error you get seems to be for another version of your code.

Comment: By using the reserved python type `str` you have redefined it and possibly broken all string manipulation functions. Change your object names so they don't conflict with Python inbuilt types.

Comment: Your question includes `python-requests` tag, but it doesn't contain anything related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run your code example verbatim. I'm not getting the error message you specified, please double-check if this is what you ran.

There is an error in your example though. At each iteration of the for loop you redeclare the "Str" variable (more on variable naming below) as the str string minus one str1 character. So everytime you remove one of the characters from str1 this does not get saved the next iteration. My output is:

```
~/Programming$ python yourcode.py
fogFogFogffffooobirdsandthebeesfogFog
```

This is to be expected, since at the last iteration of the for loop Str is declared as str1 with 'G' removed.

You perhaps (?) intended to refer to your "str" variable and simply miscapitalized. If that is the case your intended code would be:

```
str="fogFogFogffffooobirdsandthebeesGGGfogFog"

str1=['f','o','g','F','O','G']

for i in str1:
    str=str.replace(i,'')
print(str)
```

The above example will give you the output required. Note that this time the str variable is constantly redeclared as itself minus one str1 character. so the next iteration the character will still be missing from the str on the right hand side.

**On variable naming**

In general, it is a best practice to use *descriptive* variable names in your code. Calling a String "str" is not very descriptive, as it does not distinguish it from other strings. "str" is also a [type in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp), redefining it in your code will break things.
Furthermore, the variable you named "str1" is not actually a string, but a list. That would be confusing for someone reading it.
You might consider something like:

```
result_string ="fogFogFogffffooobirdsandthebeesGGGfogFog"

forbidden_characters=['f','o','g','F','O','G']

for i in forbidden_characters:
    result_string =result_string.replace(i,'')
print(Str)
```

This makes your code more readable, both for yourself, and (more importantly) for other people who might work on your code (like me :)). This is especially important if you work in a team.

In python the convention is for variable names to be [lowercase with underscores between words.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

Comment: Thanks, @Leon. I don't understand that my code works perfectly without any errors.

Comment: It's my mistake instead of adding **str1="fogFOG" ** I have added in the list. Error occurs when I try to implement the same method using the above mention "str1".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `re.sub()` to substitute all the characters in `str` from `str1` with blank:

```
from re import sub

str1 = "fogFOG"

str = "fogFogFogffffooobirdsandthebeesGGGfogFog"
print(sub(f"[{str1}]",'',str))

str = "fogfogfffoooofftreesggfoogfog"
print(sub(f"[{str1}]",'',str))
```

Output:

```
birdsandthebees
trees
```

Please note that it is a bad practice to use the names of existing built-in methods as variable names.